# Error spawning cmd.exe while building Visual C++ 2005 project

Tags: visual-studio-2005, build-process

I was changing the vc++ include directory with new paths
suddenly getting below error

erProject : error PRJ0003 : Error spawning 'cmd.exe'.

Comment: This actually helped me. I was having problem running CMAKE with VC 2008. For some reason it was trying to spawn cmd.exe and I had to include C:\windows\system32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page helped me to solve the problem

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/09/12/cmdspawnerror